# Algorithm to determine if 2 arrays are disjoint

Tags: algorithm, hash

Give a randomized expected linear-time algorithm using ideal hash functions that determines 
whether two arrays A[1..n] and B[1..n] are disjoint, i.e., whether no element of A is also an element of B.

Can anyone show me how to do this or even how to start thinking about it?

Answer (score 3):

```
for element in a:
  hasha{element} = 1

for element in b:
  if hasha{element} == 1:
    print element "found in both"
```

Time: O(len(a)+len(b))